# gcc ошибка (multiple definition) при использовании массива указателей на функции. Как исправить?

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели

При компиляции программы возникает ошибка. Никак не получается исправить её? Что я делаю не так? Есть основной файл main.c, заголовочный print.h и вспомогательный print.c. В print.h объявлены функции и массив указателей на них, в print.c соответственно их реализация, а в main.c передача этих функций как параметров в другую функцию, причем, используя в качестве указателей элементы массива. Сборка через Makefile (main: main.c print.c print.h / gcc -o main main.c print.c). Ниже приведен упрощенный текст программ.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include "print.h"

int main() {
    stack_print(print_element[0]);
    stack_print(print_int);
    stack_print(print_element[1]);
    stack_print(print_string);
    stack_print(print_element[2]);
    stack_print(print_struct);
}
```

print.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

typedef void (*stack_print_cb_t)(void);
void stack_print(stack_print_cb_t print_cb);
void print_int();
void print_string();
void print_struct();
stack_print_cb_t print_element[]={
    print_int,
    print_string,
    print_struct};
#endif // STACK_H
```

print.c

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include "print.h"

void print_int(){
    printf("print1"); 
}

void print_string(){
    printf("print2");
}

void print_struct(){
    printf("print3");
}

void stack_print(stack_print_cb_t print_cb){
    printf("stack_print\t");
    print_cb();
}
```

Выходят следующие ошибки:

```
/tmp/ccfIIODp.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `print_element'
/tmp/ccuOiocD.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: Ну так зачем же вы засунули *определение* переменной в заголовочный файл??? Разумеется у вас получится множественное определение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это *определение*

```
stack_print_cb_t print_element[]={
    print_int,
    print_string,
    print_struct};
```

перенесите в print.c, в print.h оставьте только *объявление*

```
extern stack_print_cb_t print_element[];
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало. Такой способ тоже был опробован, но без "extern" не работало.

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - отмечайте как принятый..